# How to check the variable value not its existance

Tags: php

Here's a simple php code:

```
if ( $var ) echo $value;
```

This statement checks if $var has value then echo it.

In fact, that's not what I want. I want to check the value of $var (which is a function such as 'is_single()' as in wordpress case).

--- update ---

To clairfy:

```
if ( $var ) echo 'var is true';
```

I don't want it to be a Boolean statement, I want it to check the value of $var, which in my case (Wordpress) `$var = 'is_single()';` Where `is_single()` is a function.

--- update 2 ---

Looks like what I want to achieve is to use a function instead of a string in the if statement.

Something like that:

```
if ( $var() ) instead of ( $var )
```

Though the `$var` is stored as a string.

Comment: The return value of the function? You have to call it, no other way.

Comment: BTW: Why haven't you used Google?

Comment: Can you show some of the real code that you're having problems with.

Comment: No, your code does not check if variable has value. It evaluates a boolean expression. This means that your code fails for all values that evaluate to false, such as `0` or `false`. Therefore, your variable can be set, can have a value and never get echoed. That's why you check whether the variable is set, using `isset($var)` and then you can perform other checks or echo the contents.

Comment: The code is related to Wordpress. I'm storing the following data in an option field: "$options['condition'] = 'is_single()';"... Now I want to check this condition with a statement like this: "if ( $options['condition'] ) echo 'This is single page';"... but this statement actually only check is the variable has value, it ignores what it says.

Comment: Post your last edit into your question to reopen it.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Wordpress itselfs since Wordpress is written in PHP

Comment: and what does is_single retrun?

Comment: is_single() is a Wordpress function that checks if the current page is an article page. Usually is used like that: is ( is_single() ) echo 'This is an article';

Comment: I don't really nderstand what you want, because your first Posted Statement was right to ckeck the content of the var

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
isset($var)
```

Up to now, your code does not check if the variable (`$var`) has a value. It evaluates a boolean expression. This means that your code fails for all values that evaluate to false, such as `0` or `false`. Therefore, your variable can be set, can have a value and never get echoed. That's why you check whether the variable is set, using `isset($var)` and then you can perform other checks or echo the contents.

See the php.net Manul for more Information => http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

*Thanks to N.B. for the further Explanation*

---

Update:

The Wordpress Function Returns a boolean, therefore `True` or `False`

```
if (is_single()) echo "is_single() is true";
```

That Displays *is_single() is true* if `is_single()` Returns True

---

Update 2

```
<Input name="var" value="<?php echo is_single();?>"/>
```

Should do it.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still a Boolean expressions like the one I posted.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I'll update my question.

Comment: Why do you use: `$var = 'is_single()';` and not `$var = is_single();`

Comment: I didn't even choose that. That's what I used: `$var = $options['var'];`... where `$options['var']` is the vaule of a text <input value="is_single()" />

Comment: that can't work, that means the value of $var is 'is_single()' - See my update

Comment: Yes, I this possible to convert the $var to a function so it can be read right in the if statement?

Comment: no is not, but why do you Need to do so? Option 1) Do it like I did in my Update or 2) just call `is_singel()` as I showed in my first update

Comment: I can't call it directly, it's a variable that's set in a text field then called. I think it should be treated as a function not  a string to achieve to work.

Comment: And why do you Need to set it in a text Field??

Comment: Because this is how it works in Wordpress, I'm making a theme where the admin can set the display option of sidebars based on conditional tags he insert in a text field, for example when he inserts 'is_single()' (without the quotations), the code should translate it to a function.

Comment: That can't work becouse the PHP Interpreater does't recognize a function in a string, it would be a big leck of security anyway! You Need to make some extra conditions to filter the Input String for the Functions etc. and then create your end Statement or whatever you want

Comment: Well look into it. Thanks alot.. You're the MVP!